# How to label placement and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am wrting my first webapp using bootstrap, and have two questions about the layout of my form. It currently looks like:
[Search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL0QU.png)
I would like to change a few thinkgs, but between all options of bootstrap I cannot find the right ones.

1. How to align the "include subtypes" checkbox with the object type text box?
2. The "Select an option" label is further from the radiobutton than the labels of the other inputs. How to make the (vertical) distance right? I tried several things with id="search_comb" on the label
   and for="search_comb" on the form-group and the radiobutton div's.
3. How to align the submit button in the lower right corner?

I have been experimenting with class="form-control" on several input tags, but do not completely understand the concepts. Maybe a good reference guide helps. So far I only found tutorials, very good ones, but they not are not very helpfull when trying to solve a problem with you own code.

My code currently looks like:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Search my database</h1>
            <form class="form-vertical" action="/search/" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="relation">Relation:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="relation1">
                                <option>is part of</option>
                                <option>is alternative for</option>
                                <option>is a kind of</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="object1">Object:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="object1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" value="subtype_cbx1">Including subtype</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="search_comb">Select an option:</label>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="search_combination" id="search_comb">
                                    Option1
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <input type="radio" name="search_combination">
                                    Option2
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="submit" action="search" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of the question: https://jsfiddle.net/3nxypkbw/1/